# Angular adding new content to an app that has been deployed

Tags: angular

I Have been charged with adding new content to an existing Angular app that has been deployed to a web server. I do not have access to the original application, so can only clone what is already there. I am able to run the app locally by installing npm. Can I get advice as to the way forward. Do I create a new app and add the existing scripts, or can I update the content and push the changes?

Answer (score 1):

You can not add new content after deployed application **once its built.** If you need to add new content or update to your application you have to **add them locally and build it again and deploy it.**

Comment: Yes, an angular app deployed to production is optimized to minimize the bundle size. That's why it cannot be "updated".

Comment: As I do not have the original app so cannot deploy from it, what is the best way forward?